# Orchard CMS: Linking Users with Content Types or Profile Data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms

I installed the profile module http://orchardprofile.codeplex.com/ but I am wondering what's the best way to implement the following:

Let users track "BMI" via profile. User enters BMI (body mass index) via their profile and the values will be saved.  A graph will be shown illustrating the saved values over a period of time.

This is just an example.  I am wondering what's the best way to do this sort of thing...

As a supplementary question, is it possible to create a new content type and then "link" that to a particular user?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store the values over time, you should probably create your own part and have it store a list of records, each of which should have a date and a BMI value. See http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Creating-1-n-and-n-n-relations for a description of the work required to establish relationships.

Linking content items can be done easily in 1.5 using the new content picker, at least for the simplest kinds of relations.

Comment: Thank you.  The implementation is a bit above me right now as I am new, but it's good to know that it's possible.  Good job on the Orchard project.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is it possible to do this in 1.4?  I will probably upgrade anyway, but I am just wondering about the steps that would need to be taken to do this without the new content picker.

Comment: In 1.4, you would have to build your own, but it's possible, yes.

Comment: I don't have 1.5 yet so I can't implement.  I was wondering if you could tell me how this would work.  Would users be able to edit their own BMI data via their profiles or would it be in the Content tab?

Comment: I already told you. As for whether users would be able to edit their data, that's your call. If you implement it this way, they will.

Comment: I downloaded the sample file http://docs.orchardproject.net/Attachments/Creating-1-n-and-n-n-relations/Orchard.Module.RelationSample.0.5.0.zip and was trying to install it as a module but I get the error Package uploading and installation failed.

Comment: Also, I notice the profile module is a content part so I can only add fields to it.  Do I have to turn the BMI content type into a field?  Thanks for helping me to understand how this can be accomplished.

Comment: It is not a package, it's a zip file. Extract it and copy the contents into the modules folder of your site. I don't know how the profile module you're using is working, but it makes sense that it would use fields for easy admin dashboard extensibility. That doesn't mean that you can't add parts to the User type.

Comment: I installed 1.5.1.  How do I "link content items using the new content picker?"  The goal of my design is to let users (1) keep track of their BMI (many).

Comment: You just add the content picker part and configure it. But in your case, I would recommend (again) making BMI measurements simple records, that I would link to a custom part, following the instructions in the article I linked to. Having a content type for measurements seems overkill.

Comment: I definitely want to do what you suggest.  For some reason I am finding it difficult to understand your blueprint.  Can you spell it out for me in a different way?  I believe I just need a simple set of instructions.  I can expand upon a simple framework later (by adding graphing functionalities) but I would just like to get the basic relationship between users and their BMI records up and running.

Comment: You want n BMI measurements per user. Create a BmiRecord class that has an id, a datetime and a bmi columns, plus a content item id column in order to be able to link your measurements to a user. Then, create a part that will gather the list of records for the current item. Basically follow the instructions in the article for the details.